# How to remove visible pixels from background-image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, repeat

I have a problem with `background-image`. In some resolutions I see that my frame begins to duplicate inside. If I decrease value of `background-size` then problem inside is solved but begins to duplicate outside. I have no idea how could I force the `background-image` to not duplicate on all widths. My section looks like:

```
background-image: url('...');
background-position: center;
background-size: 16.5%;
background-color: #000000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0 3.1% 3.1%;
```

[image: Here is duplicate inside]
[image: Here is duplicate outside]
[image: How it should look]

Comment: add a fiddle, it would be better to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```